# Android Back Arrow icon on ActionBar not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason this activity has the back arrow in the actionbar, but when it is clicked it has no reaction, doesn't even seen to recognize the click.  I have other activities that are similar that work fine though.  Here is the code with some stuff removed:

```
public class LanguageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "LanguageActivity";

        @InjectView(R.id.listView)
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

        @State
        String selectedLang;

        LangViewHolder selectedHolder = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);
            ButterKnife.inject(this);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            setTitle(R.string.ad_title_settings_lang);

            selectedLang = PreferencesFacade.getInstance().getCurrentLang();

            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new TrueWrapContentLinearLayoutManager(this));

            List<Pair<String, String>> langList = new LinkedList<>();

            langList.add(Constants.Languages.US);
            langList.add(Constants.Languages.LATIN_AMERICA_SPANISH);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewMappedArrayAdapter(R.layout.view_language_item, new LangViewHolder(mRecyclerView), langList));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case android.R.id.home:
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void finish() {
            super.finish();
            PreferencesFacade.getInstance().setCurrentLang(selectedLang);
            Log.v(TAG, "Finishing?");
        }
        public class LangViewHolder extends RecycleViewMappedArrayAdapter.ViewHolder<Pair<String, String>>{
   ...
        }
    }
```

Manifest snippet:

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.LanguageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```
Toolbar tBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(tBar); // sets the Toolbar as the actionbar 

tBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));

tBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed(); // calls the System onBackPressed method
        }

    });
```

Update:

getDrawable(int id) is depreciated so you should change this line of code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){ 

   tBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));

} else {

   tBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));

}
```

Comment: well, although the toolbar is visible it was covered by the recycleview I had below it...

Answer (score 1):

why don't You extend AppCompatActivity(i think actionbaractivity is deprecated...)
?

and

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.the_id);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//try this instead

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I extended AppCompatActivity and did roughly what you and @edwinj said and it is still not working.  It seems like the drawable is disabled.

Comment: what about adding this?        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);